# How to pre-format a date in Postgres automatically for all SELECT queries

Tags: node.js, postgresql, date, timestamp

I'm working with Postgres `TIMESTAMP` data types and want to change the display format anytime a `SELECT` query is called.

I currently have it working as shown below:

`SELECT to_char(my_time_col, 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS') as time_col
FROM my_table`

Is there a way to have it formatted as `2018/05/31 13:00:00` for all queries either via some predefined function, or trigger (or something that I don't know about) without having to manually format the `DATETIME` fields for each individual query? In other words — I just want to type this:

`SELECT my_time_col
FROM my_table`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried to look for it? There's plenty in the official documentation: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-formatting.html

Comment: Your SQL client formats the timestamp value. Check the configuration of the SQL client you are usnig

Comment: that depends if the client is using the binary or the ascii interface.

Answer (score 1):

run this sql:

```
SET datestyle to 'ISO, DMY';
```

so long as you don't store fractional seconds you should get the result you want.

this setting is temporary but can be made permanent by prefixing it with

`ALTER USER`*username*

or

`ALTER DATABASE`*databasename*

Answer (score 0):

There is no such setting.

The best thing is to let the application take care of the formatting.